# RabbitMQ TLS Authentication

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

There is a task to configure the operation of some web services using certificate authorization.
There is:
Erlang 22.3.3
RabbitMQ 3.8.3
It makes no sense to describe their installation.
What has been done next:
1. In accordance with the article (https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html) we perform the following actions:

```
git clone https://github.com/michaelklishin/tls-gen tls-gen
cd tls-gen / basic
CN = client PASSWORD = 123 make
make verify
make info
```

2. Copy the created certificates, change the owner

   `mv testca/ /etc/rabbitmq/
   mv server/ /etc/rabbitmq/
   mv client/ /etc/rabbitmq/
   chown -R rabbitmq: /etc/rabbitmq/testca
   chown -R rabbitmq: /etc/rabbitmq/server
   chown -R rabbitmq: /etc/rabbitmq/client`
3. We bring the configuration file to the form (/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config):

   `[
     {ssl, [{versions, ['tlsv1.2', 'tlsv1.1', tlsv1]}]},
     {rabbit, [
        {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
   {auth_mechanisms, ['PLAIN', 'AMQPLAIN', 'EXTERNAL']},
   {ssl_cert_login_from, 'client'},
        {ssl_options, [{cacertfile, "/ etc / rabbitmq / testca / cacert.pem"},
                       {certfile, "/ etc / rabbitmq / server / cert.pem"},
                       {keyfile, "/ etc / rabbitmq / server / key.pem"},
   {verify, verify_peer},
                       {fail_if_no_peer_cert, true}]}]}}
   ].`
4. We start the server, try to connect from the client. We get the error:

   2020-05-18 17: 21: 57.166 +03: 00 [ERR] Failed to connect to broker 10.10.11.16, port 5671, vhost dmz
   RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
    ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.PossibleAuthenticationFailureException: Possibly caused by authentication failure
    ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Library, code = 0, text = 'End of stream', classId = 0, methodId = 0, cause = System .IO.EndOfStreamException: Reached the end of the stream. Possible authentication failure.
      at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.InboundFrame.ReadFrom (Stream reader)
      at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ReadFrame ()
      at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.MainLoopIteration ()
      at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.MainLoop ()
      at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SimpleBlockingRpcContinuation.GetReply (TimeSpan timeout)
      at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.ConnectionStartOk (IDictionary`2 clientProperties, String mechanism, Byte [] response, String locale)
      at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.StartAndTune ()
      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
      at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.StartAndTune ()
      at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.Open (Boolean insist)
      at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection..ctor (IConnectionFactory factory, Boolean insist, IFrameHandler frameHandler, String clientProvidedName)
      at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.ProtocolBase.CreateConnection (IConnectionFactory factory, Boolean insist, IFrameHandler frameHandler, String clientProvidedName)
      at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection (IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
      at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection (IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
      at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection (String clientProvidedName)
      at EasyNetQ.ConnectionFactoryWrapper.CreateConnection ()
      at EasyNetQ.PersistentConnection.TryToConnect ()

In the rabbitmq log:

```
2020-05-18 17: 24: 59.880 [info] <0.3442.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.3442.0> (10/10/15/14/1561 -> 10/10/11/166767)
2020-05-18 17: 25: 02.887 [error] <0.3442.0> closing AMQP connection <0.3442.0> (10/10/15/14/1561 -> 10/10/11/1667671):
{handshake_error, starting, 0, {error, function_clause, 'connection.start_ok', [{rabbit_ssl, peer_cert_auth_name, [client, << 48,130,3,42,48,130,2,18,160,3,2,1,2,2 , 1,2,48,13,6,9,42,134,72,134,247,13,1,1,11,5,0,48,4,49,49,32,48,30,6,3,85,4,3 12,23,84,76,83,71,101,110,83,101,108,102,83,105,103,110,101,100,116,82,111,111,116,67,65,49,13,48,11,6,3,85,4,7,12,4,36,36,36 , 36.48,30,23,13,50,48,48,53,49,56,49,52,48,49,53,53,90,23,13,51,48,48,53,49 , 54,49,52,48,49,53,53,90,48,34,49,15,48,13,6,3,85,4,3,12,6,99,108,105,101,110,116,49,15,48 , 13,6,3,85,4,10,12,6,99,108,105,101,110,116,48,130,1,34,48,13,6,9,42,134,72,134,247,13,1,1,1,5,0,3,130 1,15,0,48,130,1,10,2,130,1,1,0,183,198,116,156,3,177,131,5,148,11,154,34,99,210,88,115,60,228,180,245,80,212,113,57,181,249,20,5,164,49,72,95,153,116,103,49 , 58,119,15,48,147,107,112,243,105,122,189,44,0,193,114,138,169,250,165,97,188,158,188,95,163,37,30,75,143,21,103,11,131,223,124,96,244,111,210,30,8,175,72,206,162,14,86,63,146,215,179,226,239,48,76,122,150,200,183,82,114,1 73,116,32,224,202,196,129,131,96,34,237,34,144,177,92,200,105,212,0,133,141,118,146,229,140,246,229,137,0,9,27,180,163,233,134,0,187,110,9,126,92,172,105,96,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,1,118,11,11,118,11,118,11,118,11,118,11,118,11,118,11,118,11,118,11,118,11,118,11,118,1,118,11,11,118,11,11,11,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,111,1'''1,11,11,1'''1,1''''N''O'', '' 92,181,68,172,135,15,90,152,209,242,31,138,135,34,95,29,162,226,175,253,176,14
```

---

**UPDATE**
New rabbitmq.config:

```
[
        {rabbit,[
        {auth_backends, [rabbit_auth_backend_internal]},
                {auth_mechanisms, ['PLAIN', 'AMQPLAIN', 'EXTERNAL']},
                {ssl_listeners,[5671]},
                {ssl_options,[
                            {versions,['tlsv1.2', 'tlsv1.1']},
                            {cacertfile, "/etc/rabbitmq/testca/cacert.pem"},
                            {certfile, "/etc/rabbitmq/server/cert.pem"},
                            {keyfile, "/etc/rabbitmq/server/key.pem"},
                            {verify,verify_peer},
                            {fail_if_no_peer_cert,true}]}
        ]}
].
```

New error:

```
2020-05-18 18:48:56.681 [info] <0.1410.0> Connection <0.1410.0> (10.10.15.14:52744 -> 10.10.11.16:5671) has a client-provided name: Viber.CallbackService.dll
2020-05-18 18:48:56.682 [error] <0.1410.0> Error on AMQP connection <0.1410.0> (10.10.15.14:52744 -> 10.10.11.16:5671, state: starting):
EXTERNAL login refused: user 'O=client,CN=client' - invalid credentials
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled the ssl plugin and restarted the broker?

```
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl

sudo systemctl restart rabbitmq-server
```

You may also try and set the following in rabbitmq.conf:

```
ssl_cert_login_from   = common_name

ssl_options.password  = 123
```

And create a user called `client` in the broker to match the CN name in your certificate.